# Nextjs: Is posible to pass object when router.push() using app dir?

Tags: next.js, next-router

I create an `Nextjs` app using `/app` dir.

I create `multi language` for my app, and a `button` to switch language.

```
'use client'

import { useParams, usePathname, useRouter } from 'next/navigation'
import { language } from '~/helper/data/common'

function SwitchLang() {

  const router = useRouter()
  const params = useParams()
  const pathname = usePathname()

  console.log(params)

  const localeData = language.find((item) => item.key === params.lang)

  const handleChange = (key: string) => {
    if (key !== params.lang) {
      router.push(pathname, {
        params: {
          ...params,
          lang: key
        }
      })
    }
  }

  return (
    <div
      className="relative border border-common-black px-2 py-1 rounded select-none cursor-pointer"
    >
      <div className="w-6 text-center">{localeData?.label}</div>
        <div className="absolute left-0 top-[calc(100%+2px)] w-full shadow-lg bg-common-white rounded ">
          {language.map((item, index) => (
            <div
              key={index}
              className="px-2 py-1 hover:bg-[#ddd] text-center"
              onClick={() => handleChange(item.key)}
            >
              {item.label}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SwitchLang
```

Ex: I have a route: `/[lang]/product/[id]. In browser:` /en/product/3`

I want when change language, the rout change into `/vi/product/3`.

In `nextjs` with `pages` dir. I can do it easily.

But with `app` dir, new `useRouter` from `next/navigation`.

The `params` when I `console.log()` is : `{lang: 'en', id: '3'}`

I try to use

```
router.push(pathname, {
  params: {
    ...params,
    lang: key
  }
})
```

but is does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App router [does not support](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router#userouter) `push` with query params.

Instead, you want to build the link yourself, for example:

```
router.push(`/${key}/product/${params.id}`)
```

Comment: The `SwitchLang` is common conponent, used for whole app.  So the route is mutable. Hard code is imposible.

Comment: Then construct it using manually using `const pathname = usePathname()`